# Appending multiple values to a list in Python while incrementing through another list

Tags: python, list

The goal of this is to enter an amount and date for each account on a regular basis.  The accounts are static (but more could be appended).  What I am trying to do is loop through each account and for each account enter the amount and date.  I am doing something wrong, I think in the increment line, and possibly the append line

After that I'd like to print the results to the screen in a way that makes sense (I know what I have is not correct and won't display in a sensible way)

Any ideas?  Thanks

```
account = ['401k', 'RothIRA', 'HSA']
amount = []
date = []

while True:
    print('Enter the amount for your ' + account[0] + ' account')
    act = input()
    amount.append(act)
    print('Enter the date for this total')
    dt = input()
    date.append(dt)
    account[] += 1
    if act == '':
        break


print(account, amount, date)
```

Comment: Your solution is screaming for a dictionary. I strongly suggest you use a dictionary for crafting this.

Comment: No need for `account[] += 1`. When you do `append` list size is automatically incremented.

Comment: @idjaw  thanks, I tried a dictionary but didn't get very far with that either

Comment: If your final solution is really this simple, read up on how to use [Python Dictionaries](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm). They are great for this kind of problem. If you need more functionality, consider defining your own object `class` for each account so that you don't need to be counting at the same time; that will give you more control over every account.

Comment: @ksai the account [] += 1 was meant for the hardcoded accounts, and looping through them while populating the other 2 lists

Comment: @JD2775 OK. Can you put together your code here when you tried doing the dictionary solution? That should be the way to go. Maybe you were close?

Comment: @JD2775 then you should use `defaultdict`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
i = 0

while i < len(account):
    print('Enter the amount for your ' + account[i] + ' account')
    act = input()
    amount.append(act)
    print('Enter the date for this total')
    dt = input()
    date.append(dt)
    i += 1
```

It's better to use for loop as follows.

```
for i in account:
    print ('Enter amount for your',i,'account')
    act = input()
    amount.append(act)
    print ('Enter date')
    dt = input()
    date.append(dt)
```

Also all your lists (account, amount, date) are linked by index. It's much cleaner to use dictionary as someone else posted.

Answer (score 1):

After a slight change in your data structure:

```
account={ '401K': { 'amount' : 0, 'date': 0 },
          'ROthIRA': { 'amount':0, 'date': 0},
          'HSA': { 'amount': 0, 'date': 0} }

for eachKey in account.keys:
    account[eachKey]['amount'] = input()
    account[eachKey]['date'] = input()


print account
```

Comment: Thank you both.  Clearly I need to look into dictionaries to make this work better.  Thank you both for the code examples